# How to cast List<T> to a derived class of T

Tags: c#

`AnswerRecords` return a list of `DnsRecordBase`:

```
List<DnsRecordBase> _Records = _DnsMessage.AnswerRecords;
```

`MxRecord` inherit from `DnsRecordBase`:

```
public class MxRecord : DnsRecordBase
```

How to cast `_Records` has a list of `MxRecord` ?

I have tried:

```
List<MxRecord> _Records = (MxRecord)_DnsMessage.AnswerRecords;
List<MxRecord> _Records = _DnsMessage.AnswerRecords as MxRecord;
```

This syntaxes doesn't work :)

Comment: @nvoigt While that answers the question, that's not actually duplicate that is exactly other way around

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work if all elements in `_Records` are `MxRecord`

```
List<DnsRecordBase> _Records = _DnsMessage.AnswerRecords;
List<MxRecord> _MxRecords = _Records.Cast<MxRecord>().ToList();
```

Comment: if they're not all of type MxRecord, you can use the `Enumerable.OfType<MxRecord>()` method to get only items that are MxRecords

Comment: Thanks that work. I did not know the cast method. So in one line :                 `List<MxRecord> _Records = _DnsMessage.AnswerRecords.OfType<MxRecord>().Cast<MxRecord>().ToList();`

Comment: If you use `OfType` you don't need a cast then